# Filled in R gradient curve

Tags: r, 3d

I have a curve I am using R to make (see code below):

```
library(rgl)

y = seq(-5,25,by=0.01)
x = seq(5,20,by=0.02)

sd = 0.3*x
NAs <- rep(NA, length(x)*length(y))
z <- matrix(NAs, length(x), byrow = T)
for(i in seq(1,length(x))) {
    for(j in seq(1,length(y))) {
        val = dnorm(y[j],mean=7.5,sd=sd[i])     
        z[i,j] = val
        if(z[i,j] < 0.02) {
            z[i,j] = NA
        }
    }
}

col <- rainbow(length(x))[rank(x)]        

open3d()
persp3d(x,y,z,color=col,xlim=c(5,20),ylim=c(5,10),axes=F,box=F,xlab="exp",ylab="obs",zlab="p")
```

And here's what it makes:
[image]

If you rotate it a bit, you'd be able to see that this is a hollow tube type figure.

[image]

But I'm trying to make it be filled in (with the color gradient) so that it's not hollow. Imagine taking a slice at any location, and you'd get a 2D plane, not a 2D curve, if that makes sense. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove the shading? Or do you want a solid shape, so your first figure will be filled to the ground?

Comment: I think you want to add rgl elements, probably using `rgl.quads`, to define the other three bounding surfaces (left, right, bottom).

Comment: A more *R*-ish and quicker way to obtain your data would be to use sapply (lines separated by semicolons):
    q <- t(sapply(x, function(i) dnorm(y, 7.5, .3*i)));
    q[q<.02] <- NA;
    identical(z, q) # TRUE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fill a gap (a 2-d shape) in 3-d you should not use lines, since they are 1-d objects. Fill the gap with triagles or quads (flat objects with four corners) instead.

```
library(rgl)

y <- seq(-5,25,by=0.1)
x <- seq(5,20,by=0.2)
z <- outer(.3*x, y, function(my.sd, my.y) dnorm(my.y, mean=7.5, sd=my.sd))
z[z < .02] <- NA

col <- rainbow(length(x))[rank(x)]        
xn <- length(x)
yn <- length(y)

open3d()
persp3d(x, y, z, color=col, xlim=c(5,20), ylim=c(5,10), axes=F, box=F,
        xlab="exp", ylab="obs", zlab="p")
rgl.quads(rep(x[xn], (yn-1)*4),
          sapply(2:yn, function(i) y[i-c(0:1,1:0)]),
          sapply(2:yn, function(i) c(z[xn,i-0:1], 0, 0)),
          color=col[xn])
```

[image]

The `outer` and `sapply` commands might be confusing if you are not that familiar to R, but think of them as vectorized `for` loops. The `outer` call does an outer join of the coordinates to create all of `z` in one go and the `sapply`s extract the coordinates of the quads. The reason for avoiding `for` loops in R (or any other high level non-compiled language) is that they are terribly slow and also make the code bulky.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this, after spending lots of time figuring out something more elegant, is to manually add lines to fill the gap:

```
yy = seq(-5, 25, by=0.01)
xx = rep(5,length(yy))
sds = 0.7 * xx
val = rep(NA, length(xx))
for(i in seq(1,length(val))) {
    val[i] = dnorm(yy[i],mean=rep(7.5,length(xx[i])),sd=sds[i])
    t = 0.06
    if(val[i] > 0.02) {
        #val[i] = t
        lines3d(c(xx[i],xx[i]),c(yy[i],yy[i]),c(0.02,val[i]),color="red")
    }
}
```